# typescript define mapping converter between two types to specific fields and types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Lets say I have two classes, both with the same fields but different types.
Now I want to define an object as list of field mappings between those classes.

with the help of [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) I came to following approach:

```
    interface IExtendedApiFormFieldType<ModelValueType, ApiValueType> {
    
        get value(): ModelValueType | undefined;
        set value(val: ModelValueType | undefined);
    
        convertToApiValue(): ApiValueType | undefined;
        convertToModelValue(val?: ApiValueType): ModelValueType | undefined;
        
    }
    
    interface IApiFieldMapper<ModelType extends IExtendedApiFormFieldType<ModelValueType, ApiValueType>, ModelValueType, ApiValueType>{
        updateModelValue(field: ModelType, val: ApiValueType): void;
        convertToApiValue(field: ModelType): ApiValueType | undefined;
    }
    
    interface ModelClass{
        name1: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number>;
        name2: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<string, string>;
    }
    
    interface ApiClass{
        name1: number;
        name2: string;
    }
    
    type ApiMapping<M extends Record<`${string & keyof A}`, any>, A> = {
        [key in string & keyof A]?: IApiFieldMapper<M[`${key}`], key, A[key]>;
    }
    
     const mapp1: ApiMapping<ModelClass, ApiClass> = {
        name1: {
            updateModelValue(field: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number>, val: number): void{
                field.value = val;
            },
            convertToApiValue(field: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number>): number | undefined{
                return field.value;
            }
        }
     };
    
     class t1 implements ModelClass{
        name1!: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number>;
        name2!: IExtendedApiFormFieldType<string, string>;
    
        t1(apiObj: ApiClass): void{
           for (const key in Object.keys(mapp1)) {
               const modelKey = key as keyof this;
               const apiKey = key as keyof ApiClass;
               const apiMappingKey = key as keyof ApiMapping<ModelClass, ApiClass>;
               mapp1[apiMappingKey]?.updateModelValue(this[modelKey] , apiObj[apiKey]);
             }
        }
     }
    }
```

here still exists a compile error on the last line.
`mapp1[apiMappingKey]?.updateModelValue(this[modelKey] , apiObj[apiKey]);`

the following error occurs:

```
Argument of type 'IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number> | IExtendedApiFormFieldType<string, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number> & IExtendedApiFormFieldType<string, string>'.
  Type 'IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number>' is not assignable to type 'IExtendedApiFormFieldType<number, number> & IExtendedApiFormFieldType<string, string>'.
```

But how can that type be determined?

Is something like that even possible with typescript?

Someone has any ideas?

Basically I want to loop through all ApiClass keys and set the value in the mapped keys in the ModelClass and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What type *explicitly* is your expected output? It's straightforward enough to convert between the two or convert both to something else, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpjK7w), but I don't know which, if any of those, is your goal.  Could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL3AkN) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: thanks for your comment. it's going in the right direction. But I need that as generic type. Imagine 100 different ModelClass / ApiClass mappings ...
I updated my question accordingly

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbE1oN) then?  If not I really need some more example code that shows exactly what goes in and comes out (e.g., I don't understand how `ApiMapping<ApiType>` could act on just one type parameter when it needs to map two things).  Let me know.

Comment: exactly thats my point. how can the second type parameter be mapped.
here I made a try, but the last part doesnt work, because the type of modelvaluetype cannot be inferred(line 51).

Comment: [see here](https://tsplay.dev/mMXL6N)

Comment: So the problem you're having is with the implementation of a generic method and not the actual types? Then the definition of `ApiMapping` is not the issue. In your question when you say "I tried that with mapping types but always get compile errors", it's helpful for the question to include examples that show the errors you're talking about. Otherwise it takes days of back and forth to converge on an answerable question (and in the meantime the question is getting stale and people might not remember the context). Could you [edit] the question to include the right code so that it's a [mre]?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkD1Dw) work for you?  Note that you are no longer even modifying the keys so the code could be simplified.  If it works I'll write up an answer; if not, please make sure that we're not just running into a subsequent issue (we shouldn't be changing the scope of this question any further) and [edit] to demonstrate the failed use case.